# remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/my-branch

Tags: github

I want all the branches to pass the status checks when PR is created so I set this rule in github - "Require status checks to pass before merging" with a few status checks

I have a local branch "my-branch" when I try to push to origin and set upstream with "git push --set-upstream origin my-branch" I am getting the following error:

"remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/my-branch.

remote: error: Required status check "my check" is expected.

To https://github.com/ProvenAI/proven-quiz.git

! [remote rejected]     my-branch -> my-branch (protected branch hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ProvenAI/proven-quiz.git'"

The github docs says - "When enabled, commits must first be pushed to another branch, then merged or pushed directly to a branch that matches this rule after status checks have passed."

Can someone help me understand why the rule that should be applied to the PR creation(based on what the docs says) gives me an error when I try to perform completely different operation(creating a new branch in origin from local)?

I'm trying to set the protection on PR creation not on the branch creation